# Providing a Java library with different code for different versions of a dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I want to write a helper library of methods around dependencies X, Y, Z at multiple versions, so that projects that import my helper library aren't forced to upgrade or downgrade their versions of X, Y, and Z that don't match mine.

I know that the projects can `<exclude>` transitive dependencies, but this is specifically for incompatible, breaking changes across versions, *e.g.*

```
X 2.0 --> getCreative()
X 3.0 --> getCreativeSlot()
```

For example, suppose we have the following projects, A, B, and C:

```
A
+---X 2.0
+---Y 0.0.53

B
+---X 3.0
+---Y 0.0.53

C
+---X 2.0
+---Y 1.0.1
```

Then I want to create this helper library:

```
H
+---X 2.0
+---X 3.0
+---Y 0.0.53
+---Y 1.0.1
```

Where I write *different* Java code for each of these versions, *e.g.* using getCreative() for X 2.0, and getCreativeSlot() for X 3.0, but either way the helper exposes getCreativeHelper(), much like an interface.

So importing this helper into projects would result in this:

```
A
+---X 2.0
+---Y 0.0.53
+---H 0.0.1
    +---X 2.0
    +---X 3.0 (excluded because Maven picks "nearest")
    +---Y 0.0.53
    +---Y 1.0.1 (excluded because Maven picks "nearest")

B
+---X 3.0
+---Y 0.0.53
+---H 0.0.1
    +---X 2.0 (excluded because Maven picks "nearest")
    +---X 3.0
    +---Y 0.0.53
    +---Y 1.0.1 (excluded because Maven picks "nearest")

C
+---X 2.0
+---Y 1.0.1
+---H 0.0.1
    +---X 2.0 (excluded because Maven picks "nearest")
    +---X 3.0
    +---Y 0.0.53 (excluded because Maven picks "nearest")
    +---Y 1.0.1
```

The assumption is that, I would be responsible for making sure that all in-between versions are backwards compatible with the nearest previous version, *e.g.*

```
D
+---X 2.5
+---Y 0.0.77
+---H 0.0.1
    +---X 2.0
    +---X 3.0 (excluded because 3.0 > 2.1; default to nearest previous, 2.0)
    +---Y 0.0.53
    +---Y 1.0.1 (excluded because 1.0.1 > 0.0.7; default to nearest previous, 0.0.53)
```

Is this possible to do with Maven or a Maven plugin? Is it possible to do with Java projects at all? Or what is the way to achieve my goal, which is: **to provide a helper library that provides helpers for multiple versions of transitive dependencies.**

Comment: What I don't understand: Why do write _different versions_ of H for the different versions of X and Y? Then you can provide a stable interface in H for changing interfaces in X and Y without trying to connect H to different versions of X at once (which is hard at best).

Comment: @JFMeier - Hm, I guess because I was trying to provide a single helper for both X and Y (and Z and ...), so even if I used separate versions, then certain tuples of versions of X-Y-Z would be linked together in a version of H. I wanted all of them to be independent. I'm starting to think the only way is to actually have separate versions HX, HY, HZ...